# Proving a_j ≤ b_j → sum (a_j) ≤ sum (b_j)

Tags: coq

I have that for all `j` in `{1, 2, .. N}` such that  `j ≠ i` it holds that `a_j ≤ b_j`. I want to prove in Coq that [image]

How can I do that and what modules are the best for these kinds of manipulations?

Comment: How did you do it in prose on paper (not in Coq?) Did you try to translate that to Coq? If so, where did you get stuck, specifically?

Comment: I didn't try to translate it, because my main concern is what is the library most suitable for sumations, since this is only the part of my proof. On paper we would use x <= y, a <= b -> x+a<=y+b

Comment: I'm not sure if there are any libraries for this, but as long as you are concerned with just finite sums, it should be relatively straightforward to implement yourself. The most obvious method would be to encode them as folded sums over lists.

Answer (score 6):

The [mathematical components library](https://math-comp.github.io/) has a theory of "big" operations with lots of lemmas. Here is how one might prove your result:

```coq
From mathcomp Require Import all_ssreflect.

Lemma test N (f g : nat -> nat) (i : 'I_N) :
  (forall j, j != i -> f i <= g i) ->
  \sum_(j < N | j != i) f i <= \sum_(j < N | j != i) g i.
Proof. move=> f_leq_g; exact: leq_sum. Qed.
```

**Edit**

If you want to reason about operations over the real numbers, you will also need to install the [mathematical components analysis library](https://github.com/math-comp/analysis).  Here is how one might adapt this proof to work over the real numbers:

```coq
(* Bring real numbers into scope, as well as
   the theory of algebraic and numeric structures *) 
Require Import Coq.Reals.Reals.
From mathcomp Require Import all_ssreflect ssralg ssrnum Rstruct reals.

(* Change summation and other notations to work over rings
   rather than the naturals *) 
Local Open Scope ring_scope.

Lemma test N (f g : nat -> R) (i : 'I_N) :
  (forall j, j != i -> f i <= g i) ->
  \sum_(j < N | j != i) f i <= \sum_(j < N | j != i) g i.
Proof. move=> f_leq_g; exact: Num.Theory.ler_sum. Qed.
```

Comment: Thanks! What should I change (include) here to have f and g : nat -> R?

Comment: @dkutlesic Just edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks! I find it very hard to read Coq documentation. Are there any resources in paper format or extensive documentation from where I can read about how to do proofs with summations?

Comment: @dkutlesic You can try the mathematical components book: https://math-comp.github.io/mcb/. Look for "big operators".

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without the mathematical components library using `lia` and induction.

```coq
Require Import Arith.
Require Import Lia.

Fixpoint sum (f: nat -> nat) (N: nat) :=
match N with
| 0 => 0
| S m => f 0 + sum (fun x => f (S x)) m
end.

Fixpoint sum_except (f: nat -> nat) (i : nat) (N: nat) {struct N} :=
match N with
| 0 => 0
| S m => 
match i with
| 0 => 0 + sum (fun x => f (S x)) m
| S j => f 0 + sum_except (fun x => f (S x)) j m
end
end.

Lemma SumLess : forall N a b,
(forall j, a j <= b j) ->
sum a N <= sum b N.
Proof.
  induction N.
  - simpl; lia.
  - intros; simpl.
    admit. (* I'll leave this as an exercise. Use lia. *)
Qed.

Lemma SumExceptLess :
forall N i a b,
(forall j, not (j = i) ->
a j <= b j) ->
sum_except a i N <= sum_except b i N.
Proof.
  induction N.
  - simpl. lia.
  - destruct i.
    simpl.
    + intros.
      apply SumLess; auto.
    + intros; simpl.
      admit. (* Again, I'll leave this for you to discover. Use lia. Follow the same pattern as you did in SumLess. *)
Qed.
```